# Percentage calculation formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two questions and I just can't figure it out. I have trying to calculate 3% into a base rate.

```
$28.54 + 3% = $29.40
```

The goal really would be to do:

```
$29.40 - 3% = $28.54
```

However, when I do the formula:

```
=B2*(1-A2
```

Two things happen, one I get a -minus sum which would work here:

```
$29.40 - 3% = $28.54
```

and two it gives me the wrong percentage. It's giving me $0.83 instead of $0.86 and I know it's because the percentage is calculating down I just don't know how to fix it.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can not calculate percentages like this. 3% of 25.54 is not the same as 3% of 29.40

Comment: You need to do B2 / (1+A2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first formula should be written out with more information to make your math work.  3% is really just 0.03.  So currently your first formula is saying

```
$ 28.54 + 3% = $ 29.40
$ 28.54 + 0.03 = $ 29.40
$ 28.57 = $ 29.40
```

The left side does not equal the right side.  There is obviously a problem.  What you are actually trying to do is:

```
$28.54 + 3% * $28.54 = $29.40
$28.54 + 0.03* $28.54 = $29.40
$28.54 + $0.86 =$29.40
$29.40=$29.40
```

Left Side equals Right Side so we know we have a working formula.

So lets assign some variables to those numbers and rearrange things so you are getting base price as the answer instead of Total

```
Base + Rate * Base = Total
Base (1+Rate) = Total
Base = Total / (1+Rate)
```

Now just substitute in your cell references for the variables and place the formula in the appropriate cell and you will be off to the races.  So assuming you want to solve for the base in  A2, with your rate in B2 and your total in E2, your formula should look like the following:

```
=E2/(1+B2)
```

[image: POC]

Comment: I can't thank you enough. you probably saved me easily 2 hours a day.... of look, confirm, copy, paste. Thank you so much!